# Laravel 5.8 artisan package:discover got rename no such file or directory error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, rename, laravel-artisan

In my laravel project, I enter command `composer update`.
It ends up error for artisan command line `php artisan package:discover --ansi` with following error.

> ErrorException  : rename(/var/www/bootstrap/cache/packages.phpq5aL7A,/var/www/bootstrap/cache/packages.php): No such file or directory

I have googled for a long time but cannot still cannot fix it. pls help.

This is a docker for window project with php 7.2-fpm.

Below is the actual error.

`www@xxxxxxxx:/var/www$ php artisan package:discover`

> ErrorException  :
>
> rename(/var/www/bootstrap/cache/packages.phpq5aL7A,/var/www/bootstrap/cache/packages.php): No such file or directory at /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:146
>       142|         chmod($tempPath, 0777 - umask());
>       143|
>       144|         file_put_contents($tempPath, $content);
>       145|
>       **146|          rename($tempPath, $path);**
>       147|     }
>       148|
>       149|     /**
>       150|      * Prepend to a file.
>
> Exception trace:
>
> 1   rename("/var/www/bootstrap/cache/packages.phpq5aL7A", "/var/www/bootstrap/cache/packages.php")
>        /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:146
>
> 2   Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem::replace("/var/www/bootstrap/cache/packages.php", "
>     array (
>       'providers' =>
>       array (
>         0 => 'BeyondCode\DumpServer\DumpServerServiceProvider',
>       ),
>     ),
>     'encore/laravel-admin' =>
>     array (
>       'providers' =>
>       array (
>         0 => 'Encore\Admin\AdminServiceProvider',
>       ),
>       'aliases' =>
>       array (
>         'Admin' => 'Encore\Admin\Facades\Admin',
>       ),
>     ),
>     'fideloper/proxy' =>
>     array (
>       'providers' =>
>       array (
>         0 => 'Fideloper\Proxy\TrustedProxyServiceProvider',
>       ),
>     ),
>     'laravel/tinker' =>
>     array (
>       'providers' =>
>       array (
>         0 => 'Laravel\Tinker\TinkerServiceProvider',
>       ),
>     ),
>     'nesbot/carbon' =>
>     array (
>       'providers' =>
>       array (
>         0 => 'Carbon\Laravel\ServiceProvider',
>       ),
>     ),
>     'nunomaduro/collision' =>
>     array (
>       'providers' =>
>       array (
>         0 => 'NunoMaduro\Collision\Adapters\Laravel\CollisionServiceProvider',
>       ),
>     ),
>     'webpatser/laravel-uuid' =>
>     array (
>       'providers' =>
>       array (
>         0 => 'Webpatser\Uuid\UuidServiceProvider',
>       ),
>       'aliases' =>
>       array (
>         'Uuid' => 'Webpatser\Uuid\Uuid',
>       ),
>     ),
>   );")
>         /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php:172

Please use the argument -v to see more details.

Comment: Clear your cache and try again.

Comment: I have tried php artisan optimize:clear, php artisan cache:clear, or other clear command. even delete bootstrap/cache folder manually. but the error still exist